# using UIGestures to remove selected uiimage?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage, gestures

I'm trying to remove an image by doing a long press gesture...
The problem is I could have multiple images on the same view. And might want to remove each image by holding down on the image.

So lets say I have:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image1;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image2;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image3;
```

all in the same view.
And now I press and hold down on Image1.
How can I get the Longpress gesture to know that Ive selected Image1 ??

```
- (void)handleDelete:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
   //Something in here to detect image is selected and delete :)
 }
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in .h file and after Try this code...

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
    longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 5;
    [longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
    [self.yourImages addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
    [longpressGesture release];

    - (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
        NSLog(@"longPressHandler");
        UIImageView *tempImage=(UIImageView*)[gestureRecognizer view];
        [tempImage removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to individual images and then when gesture is detected remove them, like following:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 3;
longPressRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.Image1 addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
[self.Image2 addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
[self.Image3 addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];

- (IBAction)longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Long Press");
    // Delete/Remove sender object
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My only question to this is now.. 
How can I remove image1 etc.
Like this?
     [if (image1 == longPressRecognizer){
      image1.alpha=0;
      }

Something like that?

Comment: What about `[image1 removeFromSuperview]` ?

Comment: Ah good point... Whats interesting though is image1 == longPressRecognizer.. I keep getting that longpressrecognizer is undeclared.. Which doesn't make sense. It was declared via UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer

Comment: Could you please update your question with the changes and also point where you are getting the error?

Comment: I think according to my code it should be (sender == image1). Also, try `[sender removeFromSuperview]` in `longPressDetected:` method.

Comment: hm.. with sender==image1 etc. I get "comparison of distinct pointer types ("UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UIImageView*)"

Comment: Sorry what about `sender.view == image1` ? Also, if you just want to remove that image then can't you just do `[sender.view removeFromSuperView]`?

Comment: I have done that => `[self.Image1 addGe...]`, `[self.Image2 addGe...]`, [self.Image3 addGe...]